# How to evoke a Makefile in the GUI?

Tags: pdf, make

Most Makefile users use the commandline. Thus they have no need of evoking it in the GUI. But Makefile can be used as an administration tool for the users too.

In my case, a clerk is tasked to maintain a document which changes daily, and as soon as she saves the file, the "source" is changed. I want her to convert it to PDF, stamp the PDF with a given template, encrypt it, merge it with a few other files, and produce three variations for different departments with different stamps.

I have a Makefile for that purpose, already written. Is there a way to let her evoke the Makefile without putting me to the mire of doing additional commandline training? She can save the document, evoke Makefile, and be done.

P.S. This is not about how to execute a shell script or an .EXE file because there is no shell scripts or .EXE files or any executable files in the question at all.

Comment: Isn't an additional `blah.sh` that runs `make; read` in the same dir as the makefile an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have two solutions for you and I prefer **Solution B**

---

### Solution A

The simplest way without a terminal is, add a wrapper script in the folder where the `Makefile` is.

1. Create a wrapper script

   ```
   nano /your/make/file/folder/makeit
   ```
2. Add two simple lines

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   make
   ```
3. Make the script executable

   ```
   chmod +x /your/make/file/folder/makeit
   ```
4. Configure nautilus to ask each time, if you double-click an executable text file

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation ask
   ```

   or for a start without asking

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation launch
   ```

---

### Solution B

A `Makefile` has the mimetype

```
text/x-makefile
```

Therefore create and use a desktop file with a wrapper script

1. Create the wrapper script

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   nano ~/bin/makeit
   ```
2. Add the code below

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   cd "$(dirname "$1")" || exit
   make
   ```
3. Create a desktop file

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/makeit.desktop
   ```
4. Add the configuration below

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Make It
   Comment=Start the make command
   Exec=/home/user/bin/makeit
   Icon=
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Editor;
   StartupNotify=true
   MimeType=text/x-makefile;
   ```

   **IMPORTANT** Replace **`user`** in the line `Exec=` with your username, the output of

   ```
   echo $USER
   ```
5. Restart Unity/GNOME Shell, for the GNOME Shell e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Nautilus with

   ```
   nautilus -q
   ```
6. Associate the `Makefile` with the `makeit` script

   - Open your file manager and right click on a `Makefile`
   - Click <kbd>Open With Other Application</kbd>
   - Click the button <kbd>View All Applications</kbd>
   - Select the entry <kbd>Make It</kbd>

Comment: I have added a second solution. Now you are spoiled for choice. **;)**

Comment: Solution B is so cool! I will use it. Marked as the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a cron job (via `crontab -e`) that runs that Makefile everyday (or even every minute).

Answer (score -1):

I discovered "Open in Terminal" feature in nautilus.

1. Right click the empty space around Makefile
2. Choose "Open in Terminal"
3. Type `make`

This isn't exactly what is asked for, but is the closest solution. Half of the difficulty in training new command-line user is the concept of current directory - in this case probably entire difficulty - making this solution look good.